# Cakephp in Vagrant: Unable to create sessions, cache, cached models

Tags: php, session, cakephp, caching, vagrant

I've been trying to run a Cakephp app inside vagrant box which is equipped with Apache2, mysql, neo4j, everything needed for the app to run. The site is opening and when I try to login in the local it's giving me this bunch of errors.

Here's the debug log :

```
2015-06-29 19:04:38 Warning: Warning (512): /vagrant/app/tmp/cache/ is not writable in [/vagrant/cake/libs/cache/file.php, line 267]

2015-06-29 19:04:38 Warning: Warning (512): /vagrant/app/tmp/cache/persistent/ is not writable in [/vagrant/cake/libs/cache/file.php, line 267]

2015-06-29 19:04:38 Warning: Warning (512): /vagrant/app/tmp/cache/models/ is not writable in [/vagrant/cake/libs/cache/file.php, line 267]

 2015-06-29 19:04:38 Warning: Warning (2): session_start(): open(/vagrant/app/tmp/sessions/sess_ojvjndme1tqt1bn4dnra8erq96, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in [/vagrant/cake/libs/cake_session.php, line 587]

 2015-06-29 19:04:38 Warning: Warning (2): Unknown: open(/vagrant/app/tmp/sessions/sess_ojvjndme1tqt1bn4dnra8erq96, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in [Unknown, line 0]

 2015-06-29 19:04:38 Warning: Warning (2): Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/vagrant/app/tmp/sessions) in [Unknown, line 0]

 2015-06-29 19:04:49 Warning: Warning (2): session_start(): open(/vagrant/app/tmp/sessions/sess_p2utf2okm73g71cv2ed361a8c7, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in [/vagrant/cake/libs/cake_session.php, line 587]

 2015-06-29 19:04:49 Warning: Warning (2): session_write_close(): open(/vagrant/app/tmp/sessions/sess_p2utf2okm73g71cv2ed361a8c7, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in [/vagrant/cake/libs/controller/controller.php, line 694]
```

I opened all permissions (by doing "sudo chmod -R 777 ." in ./tmp folder) to all folders in /tmp and still the error persists. Not sure why the app is unable to create a new session file inside the tmp directories.

**Edits & New developments** : So, I realize that as the code is being shared with the host and vagrant guest os, the tmp folder in the code is actually mounted which may be, is the reason for the permission-not-granted error.

Now the problem is now reduced to how do I create a 'tmp' folder outside of /vagrant/ folder and write all the logs, cache, sessions etc in that external folder inside the virtual os filesystem?

I've tried using the suggestions in : http://singletonio.blogspot.in/2009/01/changing-tmp-directory-of-cakephp-so-it.html

But, the new logs, sessions are not being written on ~/tmp(which is where I've set my cache, sessions, logs folders)?

Can you please help me out here?

Comment: Is there any solution that you have implemented yet, im facing the same problem trying to arrange a vm for developing on CakePHP+PostgreSQL on Vagrant

Answer (score 0):

What I did was changing Apache user in my development server from "www-data" to "vagrant".

Edit /etc/apache2/envvars:

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=vagrant
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=vagrant
```